# Using bank wire transfers

Tags: united-states, banking, money-transfer

Will any bank reports have to be filed if I send more than $10,000 in my bank account by a wire transaction to another bank account in my name in the USA?

Answer (score 1):

Not by you.

Your bank might have to fill some reports for the IRS, but for the customer, nothing needs to be done. As long as the money is not income from illegal activity you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: For further clarity, the bank is required to file a Transaction Currency Report with FinCEN. But, as you stated, there is no filing requirement for the OP, nor are there any consequences to him.

Comment: @TainToTain: You mean a [Currency Transaction Report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_transaction_report)?  As far as I know, those are only filed for transactions of *currency*, i.e. physical notes or coins, and wouldn't be used for a wire transfer.